# Detect application minimize event for UIKIt for Mac?

Tags: swift, macos, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

When i minimize the application `applicationDidEnterInBackground` not called for Mac Catalyst. After some search i found that Background delegate methods not called for Mac Catalyst but foreground method of Scene delegate called.

is there any way to track or handle minimize delegate methods like `NSWindowDelegate` have?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you check [`NSWindowDelegate.windowWillMiniaturize:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419461-windowwillminiaturize?language=objc) you'll notice that its parameter is just a notification (its name is `NSWindowWillMiniaturizeNotification`).

So, you can simply observe that notification to get notified whenever a window in your app is about to be minimized:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.willMiniaturizeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    print("This window is about to be minimized:", notification.object)
}
```

You can also do the same to get notified about other events like:

- `NSWindow.didMiniaturizeNotification`: After the window is minimized.
- `NSWindow.didDeminiaturizeNotification`: After the window is restored/deminimized.
- `NSWindow.willEnterFullScreenNotification`: Before entering full screen.
- `NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification`: After entering full screen.
- `NSWindow.willExitFullScreenNotification`: Before exiting full screen.
- `NSWindow.didExitFullScreenNotification`: After exiting full screen.

Full list of notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow?language=objc).